# Jquery is not working in localhost wamp

Tags: jquery, wamp

This is my code this works at jsfiddle
i used ready function already but is still not functioning
there are no error in google chrome f12+consoles.
I'm still new at jquery I don't know what's wrong with this.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(event) {   
    $('input').bind('keypress', function (event) 
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    });
    });
    </script>

<input>
```

Comment: Do you access code using `http://localhost` or just opening file in browser? Some code without accessing it using localhost won't work

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek — None of the code here falls into that category.

Comment: I access it using localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect your error by using [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

[image]

You missed out the `>` from the start tag for the jQuery script element.

This means that `</script` is treated as an invalid attribute.

`>` ends the start tag.

`<script type="text/javascript">` and the rest of your script is the content of the script element and is ignored because there is a `src` attribute.

The second `</script>` finally ends the script element that loads jQuery.

Comment: right fix it now i got this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: @user3840545 — Look at the end of the line above that.

Comment: No error but the code is not executing. this is so frustrating ~.~

Comment: please repost your code in a new question preferrably ... because your new problem shouldn't have anything to do with the old one ... if it's not just the missing `{` at the end of the `bind` line

Comment: ... but you shouldn't have repeated the same problem in that new question :-(